# What is the difference between weaving models and mapping models in MDE?

Tags: eclipse-emf, model-driven-development, mde

With respect to MDE, I have come across different literature regarding ***mapping models*** and ***weaving models***, which more often than not, seem to be the same thing. They are both frequently used to define correspondences between model elements and generate model transformations. Can you provide any input on this matter? Are weaving and mapping models in MDE the same thing or do they differ? Thank in advance!